# Executing Linux programs (WSL) from Windows environment

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed `git` inside *WSL* and when I call the program it shows one error message:

[image: translation: not a valid Win32 application]

My intention is to replace little by little tools like *cygwin*, *Git for Windows* and others by the tools installed inside WSL.

[image: translation: cannot/impossible execute the binary file]

Comment: I would not try and run Linux programs from WSL inside of a Windows program; you're going to need Win32 apps, not WSL apps, to work with the Windows tools.  There is [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), though, and I know it does work.

Comment: Note to mods/reviewers: that I migrated this from Ask Ubuntu, because this asks "How can I use a WSL program from a native Windows program", which would be offtopic on Ask Ubuntu, as it asks a Windows question rather than a Linux question.

Comment: can you wrap it inside an `*.sh` file and call to that script in your program?

Comment: git runs 'fine' under WSL.. by 'fine' I mean slower than dirt.. but it works 100%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not [supposed to access Linux files and utilities directly from Windows apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/). So giving the path directly is not a good thing to do.

You should call it as `bash -c "git"`, or if needed, put the call into a batch file so that Windows app will call that file instead of the Linux app.

You also need to ***translate the path*** between Windows and Linux because git in WSL won't understand things like *`D:\my project\src`*. Previously the conversion must be done manually, however MS has included [`wslpath`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/03/07/windows10v1803/) since Windows 10 1803 for that purpose.

You can also install an add-on to do all the translation and heavy lifting for you. In VSCode there's [wslgit](https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit) and JetBrains has [WSL Support Framework](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10024-wsl-support-framework). I'm not sure about Android Studio but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39285394/995714) suggests that [gitwrap](https://github.com/ardevd/gitwrap/releases) can be used

Read more [Interop between Windows and Bash](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/)

Comment: Hrrrmmm.. I do this ALL OF THE TIME.. What you don't want to edit are files under the virtual paths that AREN'T under /mnt/*.  You can run a windows command, pipe to a linux command and pipe it back to a windows command.  I use linux netbeans under windows and edit the files from both sides.  What can become confusing is if case sensitivity gets enabled without knowing it..

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get it working from IntelliJ. Even with a shell the test in IntelliJ kept complaining. You can follow this tutorial to start IntelliJ from inside WSL: https://gist.github.com/wsargent/072319c2100ac0aea4305d6f6eeacc08

Havn't tried it myself but it's rumored to be laggy.