# Integrating Linux commands in Windows (10) CMD shells

Tags: windows-10, shell, cmd.exe, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my previous (Win 7) machine I installed CygWin which allowed (due to PATH) me to call Linux commands from any command shells -- the default one, the Anaconda one, etc.

I would like to have the same ability on my new Win 10.
I installed the Linux sub-system (Ubuntu), but I cannot see any way to allow Linux commands to be used in other shells?

Is there a way to achieve this, or should I just install CygWin?

Comment: Read this [blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that Linux utilities can be run on Windows:-

- Compile the code as a native Windows .EXE file: this is what CygWin does, which is how all the individual utilities are available individually for direct invocation from a Windows shell.
- Provide an environment within Windows in which Linux native ELF binaries can run, in  a manner similar to how Linux runs Windows programs under Wine: this is what Windows Subsystem for Linux does, and the individual programs are not recognised as executables outside this environment.

The WSL environment is launched when `bash.exe` is run, and you can run WSL utilities by invoking through `bash.exe`, eg:

```
bash -c ls
```

If you need to pass parameters, you will need to quote the command string, eg:

```
bash -c 'ls -l ./Documents/'
```

I haven't checked CygWin, but some native Windows ports allow flexibility in their run strings (eg `/` instead of `-` for options, and `\` instead of `/` for directory separators) - with WSL you will need to use strict Linux run strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a duplicate of [Executing Linux programs (WSL) from Windows environment](https://superuser.com/q/1160682/241386)

As I answered in that question, to run Linux commands you'll need to invoke `bash` with the `-c` option. You also need to convert the path to the Linux version with `wslpath` if the path is not already in the Linux form. For example to run `grep` on `E:\somefile` then call it like this

```bat
bash -c "grep 'my string' $(wslpath 'E:\somefile')"
```

Do note that [single quote isn't a special character in cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24173825/995714), therefore you **must use double quotes in cmd**. `bash -c 'ls -l ./Documents/'` like what AFH said won't work. OTOH in PowerShell both `''` and `""` are used for quoting, and the meaning is the same as in bash so you can call `bash -c 'echo -e "some string"'` from PowerShell without problem

However in PowerShell also has various Linux-like aliases like `ls`, `cat`, `man`... so in many cases you can use them without resorting to WSL bash

If you use Cygwin then every Unix utility will be compiled into a separate *.exe file. You can run `which ls` or `which grep` to get their paths easily. They're run directly in the Windows environment, not WSL which is a separate subsystem